# CRC-5 correct computation?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to generate a CRC table for the standard CRC-5 algorithm, (or at least need some way to validate that the table I have is indeed correct). I was under the impression that CRC-5 would simply utilize 5 bits to calculate the CRC value, but in my table below I notice some first bytes with values greater than 7.

Is this correct and is there a link to a correct CRC5 implementation?

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
private byte[] _table = new byte[256]
{
    0x00, 0x31, 0x62, 0x53, 0xC4, 0xF5, 0xA6, 0x97,
    0xB9, 0x88, 0xDB, 0xEA, 0x7D, 0x4C, 0x1F, 0x2E,
    0x43, 0x72, 0x21, 0x10, 0x87, 0xB6, 0xE5, 0xD4,
    0xFA, 0xCB, 0x98, 0xA9, 0x3E, 0x0F, 0x5C, 0x6D,
    0x86, 0xB7, 0xE4, 0xD5, 0x42, 0x73, 0x20, 0x11,
    0x3F, 0x0E, 0x5D, 0x6C, 0xFB, 0xCA, 0x99, 0xA8,
    0xC5, 0xF4, 0xA7, 0x96, 0x01, 0x30, 0x63, 0x52,
    0x7C, 0x4D, 0x1E, 0x2F, 0xB8, 0x89, 0xDA, 0xEB,
    0x3D, 0x0C, 0x5F, 0x6E, 0xF9, 0xC8, 0x9B, 0xAA,
    0x84, 0xB5, 0xE6, 0xD7, 0x40, 0x71, 0x22, 0x13,
    0x7E, 0x4F, 0x1C, 0x2D, 0xBA, 0x8B, 0xD8, 0xE9,
    0xC7, 0xF6, 0xA5, 0x94, 0x03, 0x32, 0x61, 0x50,
    0xBB, 0x8A, 0xD9, 0xE8, 0x7F, 0x4E, 0x1D, 0x2C,
    0x02, 0x33, 0x60, 0x51, 0xC6, 0xF7, 0xA4, 0x95,
    0xF8, 0xC9, 0x9A, 0xAB, 0x3C, 0x0D, 0x5E, 0x6F,
    0x41, 0x70, 0x23, 0x12, 0x85, 0xB4, 0xE7, 0xD6,
    0x7A, 0x4B, 0x18, 0x29, 0xBE, 0x8F, 0xDC, 0xED,
    0xC3, 0xF2, 0xA1, 0x90, 0x07, 0x36, 0x65, 0x54,
    0x39, 0x08, 0x5B, 0x6A, 0xFD, 0xCC, 0x9F, 0xAE,
    0x80, 0xB1, 0xE2, 0xD3, 0x44, 0x75, 0x26, 0x17,
    0xFC, 0xCD, 0x9E, 0xAF, 0x38, 0x09, 0x5A, 0x6B,
    0x45, 0x74, 0x27, 0x16, 0x81, 0xB0, 0xE3, 0xD2,
    0xBF, 0x8E, 0xDD, 0xEC, 0x7B, 0x4A, 0x19, 0x28,
    0x06, 0x37, 0x64, 0x55, 0xC2, 0xF3, 0xA0, 0x91,
    0x47, 0x76, 0x25, 0x14, 0x83, 0xB2, 0xE1, 0xD0,
    0xFE, 0xCF, 0x9C, 0xAD, 0x3A, 0x0B, 0x58, 0x69,
    0x04, 0x35, 0x66, 0x57, 0xC0, 0xF1, 0xA2, 0x93,
    0xBD, 0x8C, 0xDF, 0xEE, 0x79, 0x48, 0x1B, 0x2A,
    0xC1, 0xF0, 0xA3, 0x92, 0x05, 0x34, 0x67, 0x56,
    0x78, 0x49, 0x1A, 0x2B, 0xBC, 0x8D, 0xDE, 0xEF,
    0x82, 0xB3, 0xE0, 0xD1, 0x46, 0x77, 0x24, 0x15,
    0x3B, 0x0A, 0x59, 0x68, 0xFF, 0xCE, 0x9D, 0xAC
};

public static byte CalculateCrc(byte[] data, byte startIndex, int count)
{
    byte result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        result = _table[(result ^ data[ii]) & 0xFF];

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says there are three different standard CRC5 polynomials. Which are you using?

I have never worked with CRC5, but I do have some code for CRC32 (IEEE 802.3 Poly) that may help you with your algorithm.

```
static void GenerateCRCTable(void)
{
    // This is the official polynomial used by CRC32 in PKZip.
    // Often times the polynomial shown reversed as 0x04C11DB7.
    unsigned long dwPolynomial  = 0xEDB88320;
    int i                       = 0; 
    int j                       = 0; 

    unsigned long dwCrc;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        dwCrc = i;
        for(j = 8; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if(dwCrc & 1)
                dwCrc = (dwCrc >> 1) ^ dwPolynomial;
            else
                dwCrc >>= 1;
        }

        g_crcTable[i] = dwCrc;
    }
}
```

Then, in the actual CRC function (some file reading code omitted):

```
    static bool once        = false;
    wchar_t *t_pfilename    = 0;
    int nLen                = 0;

    if(once==false)
    {
        once = true;
        GenerateCRCTable();
    }

    *crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    DWORD numRead;
    DWORD i;
    unsigned long value = *crc;

    for(;;)
    {
        if((ReadFile(hCRCFile, g_crcBlock, sizeof(g_crcBlock), &numRead, 0)) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(hCRCFile);
            *crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            return 2;
        }

        if(numRead == 0)
        {
        break;
        }

        for(i=0; i<numRead; i++)
        {
            value = ((value) >> 8) ^ g_crcTable[(g_crcBlock[i]) ^ ((value) & 0x000000FF)];
        }   
    }

    *crc = ~value;
```

Comment: I am using the Rfid Gen 2 CRC 5 algorithm... or at least attempting to generate a correct table for it. And thank you for your code sample, I am going to see how it works based on a 5-bit version...

Answer (score 1):

The bytes in your table have nothing to do with the CRC size. A 32-bit CRC algorithm also (usually, virtually always) use a table of size 256. This has to do with a byte having 256 possible values, and nothing with the CRC.

Comment: But I suppose an 8-bit CRC would be different to a 5-bit CRC for instance? Even though they both take up one byte, the answer would somehow be quite different?

Comment: The actual bytes in the table will be different, but the number of bytes would be the same (256). Therefore, your implementation might be right or wrong, each individual byte will need to be checked (or just test it against a sufficiently large input).